# Replacing 3 or more digits with equivalent number of *

Tags: regular-expression

I want to replace any 3 or more digit string in a text file with equivalent number of `*`.For example: abc-1234-45 --> abc-****-45

```
echo "abc-1234-45" | sed 's/[0-9]\{3,\}/*/'
```

I tried this but it only replaces it with one *.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `perl`:

```
$ echo "abc-1234-45" | perl -pe 's/(\d{3,})/"*" x length($1)/eg'
abc-****-45
```

`/e` flag causes `perl` evaluate the right side as an expression before replacing.

Comment: Thank you. Is this not possible in `sed` or `awk` - I mean evaluating string as an expression before replacing?

Comment: @RaghavenderKavi AFAIK, `sed` and `awk` can't.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk

```
echo 'abc-1234-45' | 
awk --re-interval -v RS='[[:digit:]]{3,}' '{gsub(/[[:digit:]]/, "*", RT);
  printf "%s%s", $0, RT}'
abc-****-45
```

Or if you are willing to look at Python

```
echo 'abc-1234-45' |  python -c 'import re; import sys; print re.sub(r"\d{3,}",\
lambda x: len(x.group())*"*", sys.stdin.readline().strip())'
```